# How to set 40 bytes of data to mixer control using tinymix?

Tags: audio, controls, alsa, tinyalsa

I have a control called `EQ2 Coefficients`

the output of the tinymix command gives

```
65  BYTE    40  EQ2 Coefficients                        00000fc803fe00e01ec4f136040904cc1c9bf337040b0cbb16f8f7d9040a1f14058c056340000b75
```

How can I set that mixer control to something other value for example the value to be written into the control is `00000fb3040001341E4FF1A5040B06831B64F448040A10F413DDFA1D040A280D02A104A840000000` using tinymix command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa/blob/master/tinymix.c), `tinymix` wants a list of byte values:

```
tinymix "EQ2 Coefficients" 0 0 15 179 4 0 ...
```